# interchangeable derived class method from base class c++

Tags: c++

i am pretty sure this is a simple question for a long time c++ user, this should be a pattern or the problem should be solved in any other way but given i am Python developer and a total novice with c++ i don't know how it's usually done.

Suppose that i have a class where i want to store a pointer to an object that can be of 1 of two different classes that respects an interface, for example:

```
class AllPlayers
{
  public:
  virtual void play();
};

class VlcPlayer: public AllPlayers
{
  public:
  virtual void play();
};

class Mplayer: public AllPlayers
{
  public:
  virtual void play();
};

class MyMediaPlayer
{
  public:
  MyMediaPLayer(int playerType);
  AllPlayers m_player;
};

MyMediaPlayer::MyMediaPlayer(int PlayerType)
{
  if (PlayerType == 0) {
    VlcPlayer tmp_player;
    m_player = static_cast<AllPlayers> (tmp_player);
  }
  else {
    Mplayer tmp_player;
    m_player = static_cast<AllPlayers> (tmp_player);
  }
}

MyMediaPlayer test(0);
test.play();
```

First, i know this would not work and that it seems pretty normal why but how could i get this effect? i would like to have a member of a class for what i am going to use ever the same methods, implemented using a interface and i would like to avoid trying to cast to every of the derived classes every time i am going to use one of his methods.

Comment: Use a pointer: `AllPlayers* m_player;` and `m_player = new VlcPlayer();`.

Comment: Also if you're using the new c++11 standard and not using the pointer anywhere else use unique_ptr<AllPlayers> m_player; so you don't have to worry about destroying it afterwards.

Comment: Yeah i was trying  to mean a pointer in the example code, only that forget to write it :), didn't think would be that easy, thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is value-based, i.e., if you create an object of a given type you really have an object of this type. This doesn't play nicely with dynamic polymorphism. To get dynamic polymorphism you use a pointer or a reference to the actual object. To also get the life-time straight you typicslly allocate the corresponding object on the stack (make sure your base class has a virtual destructor if you ever release an object of a derived type using a pointer to the base). With this, you should be all set: just call a virtual function of the base class through a pointer to rhe base: When you overridethe function in the derived class this is the function which is called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i am still a bit lost with c++, i known that someway, probably in the, very big, c++ book i read sometime ago but i only touch c++ 1 week every many months, it's hard to remember all the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
AllPlayers m_player;
```

that is going to be an instance of `AllPlayers` and **cannot** be an instance of a class that derives from it.

You should instead use a pointer and allocate the class on the stack.

For example:
    class MyMediaPlayer 
    {
      public:
      MyMediaPLayer(int playerType);
      ~MyMediaPLayer();
      AllPlayers m_player;
    };

```
MyMediaPlayer::MyMediaPlayer(int PlayerType)
{
  if (PlayerType == 0) {
    m_player = new VlcPlayer;
  }
  else {
    m_player = new Mplayer;
  }
}

MyMediaPlayer::~MyMediaPlayer()
{
  if (0 != m_player) {
    delete m_player;
    m_player = 0;
  }
}
```

As suggested by @xception use of `unique_ptr` may relieve you from having to write code to deallocate the instance.

As correctly pointed out by @DietmarKühl you should always declare a virtual destructor in a root class (a base class that does not itself derives from some other class) as is the case with `AllPlayers`.

```
class AllPlayers
{
  public:
  virtual ~AllPlayers();
  virtual void play(); // note: this should probably be pure virtual.
};
```

Comment: thanks, i will take in account the destructor to not leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this will not work is colloquially known as Object Splicing. (Or, for those Harry Potter readers out there, Object Splinching)

Let's look at an example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int bob;
    float fred;

    // Foo(const Foo& otherfoo); // implicit copy constructor
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    double gabe; // gabe newell is fat
    char steve;  // steve jobs is thin

    // Bar(const Bar& otherbar); // implicit copy constructor
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    f.bob = 10;
    f.fred = 1.5;

    b.bob = 15;
    b.fred = 2.5;
    b.gabe = 1.77245385091; // sqrt(pi)
    b.steve = -4;

    f = Foo(b);
    return 0;
}
```

This is legal and valid.  Problem is, the implicit copy constructor of Foo is called, and Foo's copy constructor knows nothing about what a Bar is.  Only that it contains everything a Foo has, and some extra irrelevant crap.  Because of this, only the Foo's data gets preserved; the data unique to the Bar gets spliced off.

It's important to note that this is DEFINED BEHAVIOR: it's doing EXACTLY WHAT YOU TELL IT TO.  Casting between a subclass of a base class and a base class is implicit.  Furthermore, the behavior of the copy constructor is implicit.

It's also important to note that, under the hood, C++ pointers and references work in the same way.  It's perfectly sane to pass the Bar to Foo's copy constructor by reference, this pass by reference does not produce a copy of the object.  It's the same as working with a pointer.

The actual splicing takes place as a direct result of the copy constructor biting off more than it can chew.  It gets an object with more state than it expected, and its only choice is to ignore the extra state.

With python, this doesn't happen because everything is implicitly stored as a reference type.  Since you only work with references (the objects themselves are abstracted away), you never have the opportunity to accidentally splice an object.

Comment: And Python it's what i am used to, i am trying to learn the differences and they have many :), thanks.